# Eclipse (Android) always puts intervals instead of tabs no matter the tab policy

Tags: android, eclipse

Is this a bug in the IDE? I'm trying all different tab policies, but whenever I use Format (Cmd + Shift + F) I get only spaces (4 of them - depending on the setting in the formatter).

Does anybody know something? Really annoying.

Comment: What does 'interval' mean?

Comment: I mean space. Question edited.

Comment: This might help. It discusses the need to change two (2) settings. http://rakesh.sankar-b.com/2011/08/22/convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-eclipse-and-file-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It was the project specific settings - the formatter there was different. It was set for "Spaces only".